# Plot density distribution

Tags: plot, distribution, density-plot

I have generated a bunch of data, and want to plot how they are **distributed** using matplotlib. How should I proceed?

Thank you for answers

Comment: What have you already tried? Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hist` is a nice way to see a distribution. See [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) for details.